# Logstash grok split values in cookie string

Tags: logstash, grok

Want to split the following cookie information with grok in different fields.

**Case 1**

id=279ddd995;+user=Demo;+country=GB

**Output**

{
"id": "279ddd995",
"user": "Demo",
"country": "GB",
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out following  grok pattern

```
filter {
    grok {
         match => ["message", "id=(?<id>[^;]+);.*?user=(?<user>[^;]+);.*?country=(?<country>[^;]+).*?"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is conveniently provided in key/value pairs.  Rather than make a regexp for each field, you can use the kv{} filter to split them apart.  This has the side benefits of generically handling any keys in any order.